# Проброс портов через роутер

Tags: роутер, провайдер

Всем привет. Подскажите,никто не сталкивался с такой проблемой. У меня подлючен Triolan интернет и дома роутер d-link. Я сделал forwarding и пробросил порт на свою виртуалку на ноуте. И примерно это 2-3 дня работает а потом не могу удаленно подключится. Роутер не ребутается, все в норме.
Спасибо

Comment: 1) Проверить, действительно ли виртуалка и ноутбук доступны внутри локалки. 2) Проверить, не сменил ли провайдер внешний ID вашего подключения. значение в 2 дня похоже на срок аренды DHSP

Comment: Триолан предоставляет выделеный IP